# How to fix Number Of Row Per Page in SSRS Report?

Tags: reporting-services

I Have Fix 10 Rows Per Page , If 2records Comes From Query Then I Want To Show 8 Blank Rows. How To Fix It ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly generic example. It just counts the actual rows, calculates how many rows are required to round up to the nearest 10 and then UNIONs a query that generates blank rows.

```
SELECT * 
    FROM (
        SELECT 
                RowN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY myColumn), -- order by any column
                *
            FROM myTable
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 
            TOP (SELECT ExtraRows = (FLOOR((Count(*)+9)/10) * 10) - COUNT(*) FROM myTable) -- 10 here is rows per page
                NewRowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id]) + (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable)
                ,NULL, NULL, NULL -- one nulll value for each column in myTable
                FROM sys.all_columns
    ) u 
    ORDER by u.RowN -- add any additional required sorting here
```

If your current query is not simple then dump the results of that into a temp table

```
SELECT * 
INTO #t 
FROM ...
myBigQuery
```

then change the references to `myTable` in the main query above to `#t` or whatever the temp table is called.

---

**EDIT for using with SP**

---

If using a Stored proc then you can dump the results of that into a temp table and do the same. For exmaple

```
CREATE TABLE #t (ColA int, ColB varchar(100)....)
INSERT INTO #t
   EXEC myStoredProc

...
the main query from above
...
```

Just swap out all references to `myTable` with #t

Comment: i have used stored procedure in ssrs report

Comment: I've updated the answer to explain the changes if using an SP